# Button Handler Syntax for Dismissing ViewController in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, dismissviewcontroller

I have created a custom UIBarButton in code to dismiss a custom viewController.  The compiler does not like my syntax, however.

Here is the code to create the UIBarButtonItem:

```
//grab VC
detailC* detailVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailVC"]; //This custom VC
is a sub-class of UIViewController

//Create barbuttonitem
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png]
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:self
                                   action:@selector(dismss:detailVC)];//ERROR HERE

//Here is the dismiss method: 
-(void) dismissVC: (UIViewController*) vc {

  [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The error from the compiler is: `'Expected :'`

There is a fix option to `insert :`.  If I choose fix, it changes the selector to:

`action:@selector(dismissVC: controller:)];`

which does not make sense and also gives the warning `'Undeclared Selector"`

What am I doing wrong?

Note: this is taking place in appDelegate so I cannot use self to dismiss VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is fundamentally incorrect. The only valid parameter that your `dismissVC:` method can take is the `UIBarButtonItem` that triggered the action. You can't pass a view controller to that method.

But you don't need to. Since you want to dismiss "self", just call `dismissViewController` on `self`.

```
//Create barbuttonitem
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"]
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(dismiss:)];
```

Here's the updated method:

```
- (void)dismiss:(UIBarButtonItem *)button {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can self work in appDelegate?  Changing to self, I am getting No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:' error

Comment: I could not get self to work but I am marking this correct for pointing out proper functioning of handler.  In stead of self, I grabbed a reference to the presenting view controller through a separate method

Comment: I assumed this button code and the `dismiss` method were in the view controller that needed to be dismissed. I missed the last line of your question.